# Changing name of List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, naming

I write in my preable the following code:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm,
bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Grapheme}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Graphemes}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tables}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Introduction}
```

but when I scroll to the List of Graphemes in my PDF it still says List of Figures.

Why is this happening? 
I want it to be saying "List of Graphemes"

I'm using Kile 2.1 in Linux mint.

Comment: Are you loading any other ToC-related packages? How about compiling a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can copy-and-paste to see what you get as output. Currently, if I just add `\documenclass{report}` and an `\end{document}`, things work as expected, showing `List of Graphemes` for the List of Figures.

Comment: Sorry for the output .. I'm new and can't find out how to make a code in a comment...  I hope it is readable..

Comment: With the `babel` package and `english` as main language, the correct way is `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Graphemes}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot lockstep..!!!  It's working ... but on each figure it still says "Figure 5.3 ... Figure 5.4" etc.  How can I change each figure and say Grapheme ?

Comment: I inserted each grapheme like \begin{figure}  \end {figure}.    Probably that's why it says figure on each on... can I change it?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Grapheme}` must also be put in the argument of `\addto\captionsenglish`. See the linked Q&A.

Comment: It's working!!! Thanks a lot lockstep!!  One more question:  how can I make each caption bold? like: **Grapheme 5.28:** The occasions of usage of L1

Comment: I've got it it's with \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{]caption